# System-wide monitoring of calls to a library function

Tags: linux, ltrace, systemtap

I have a modern Linux desktop with lots of processes running concurrently. One of those processes, and I don't know which one, calls a function `some_func` from a popular dynamic library `some_lib` (think `libc` or `libx11`, so a *lot* of processes use it), and I want to know what process does that (and ideally, have a stack trace of each invocation).

How do I determine which process makes a call to `some_lib`?

Options that I've considered thus far:

1. Use `ltrace` or `latrace`: Having an `ltrace`-style detailed list
   of what process called the function I'm interested in with what
   arguments would be perfect, but `ltrace` only works with an
   individual process or process groups. I cannot just type `ltrace -e
   some_func@some_lib -fp 1` and see all uses system-wide.
2. Find what processes use my library with `lsof`, then proceed with step 1: That would be very cumbersome, since there are too many processes using the same library, but not calling said function.
3. `grep -r some_func /usr`, then see if there are only a couple of binaries capable of calling the function, and work my way from there. Although that *could* work in some limited amounts of cases, this is by no means a general solution, and wouldn't work if e.g. `some_func` is ubiquitous in various binaries but is seldom called.
4. Use the kernel audit system. If I was tracing a system call, I could type `auditctl -S some_syscall ...` and that would do the trick in logging system-wide invocations. However, `auditctl` does not seem to be capable of doing the same level of granularity with *library functions*.
5. Finally, I could *rebuild* the library, adding a new line to the function I'm interested in that would log all its invocations. While this would be guaranteed to solve my issue, that solution would be cumbersome and require modifying/recompiling the library and at least 2 reboots to roll out the instrumented library and to roll it back after finding the culprit.

Is there an easier way?

(I want to point out that this is meant to be a general question, and am mostly interested in general solutions that would Just Work.)

---

I found a nice [comparison article](http://www.brendangregg.com/blog/2015-07-08/choosing-a-linux-tracer.html) mentioning a few more tracing facilities I wasn't aware of, which may be worth exploring.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SystemTap with debuginfo can trace function calls in libraries; on a Centos 7 system:

```
$ sudo stap -L 'process("/lib64/libglib*").function("*strndup*")'
process("/usr/lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0.5000.3").function("g_strndup")
$
```

And this can be used as a `probe` point that prints backtraces or whatever you want that can be written with SystemTap:

```
probe begin {
    printf("ok\n")
}
probe process("/usr/lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0.5000.3").function("g_strndup") {
    /* printf("%s[%d]\n", execname(), pid()) */
    print_usyms(ubacktrace())
}
```

saved as `probelibraryfunc.stp` this can be run via

```
$ sudo stap probelibraryfunc.stp
```

though may produce crazy amounts of output if the call is common...

Comment: Very cool! I can confirm this works and is pretty much as good as one could wish for. I'll keep the question open for a while in case anyone wants to mention some other tracing facilities.

Comment: I suspect `dtrace` can do this too, but found not references to `sysdig`. Do you have an idea if `sysdig` could do this?